# HTML5 Audio Tag cannot raise event `canplay` on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm custom an audio player with JS and HTML5.
The first, I do simple with:

```
  <div id="btnPlayPause" playing="" state=""></div>
  <audio style="display:none;" id="realSounder" preload="meta">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">        
  </audio>
```

And JS:

```
$("#btnPlayPause").click(function(){
    realSounder = document.getElementById('realSounder');
    realSounder.src = "http://domain.com/aloha.mp3";
    realSounder.play();
});
```

It runs well. But when I implement with UI control, need more complex code:

```
function initPlayer () {
    realSounder = document.getElementById('realSounder');
    realSounder.volume = 0.8;
    subscribe('canplay', realSounder, function() {
         if (realSounder.getAttribute('state') != 'playing')
             realSounder.play();
     });
    subscribe('canplaythrough', realSounder, function() {       
        if (realSounder.getAttribute('state') != 'playing')
            realSounder.play();
    });
}
function subscribe(event, element, func) {
    //addEventListener for cross-browser. 
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
    } else {
        element['on' + event] = func;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initPlayer();
    $("#btnPlayPause").click(function(e) {      
        e.preventDefault();
        //do something for display

        play();
    });
});

function play() {
    var loadUrl = "/wap.php/AjaxLoadAudio";
    var audioId = $("#btnPlayPause").attr('playing'); //get id of audio
    
    $.getJSON(
        loadUrl,
        {audio_id:audioId},
        function(json){
            realSounder.src = json.audio_share_url;
        }
    ).error(function() {
            console.log('Error: 404');
    });    
}
```

It doesn't works. It's seem tobe `realSounder` cannot raise event `canplay` or `canplaythrough` to play sound. Why? I'm try to console.log() or alert() in handler function at `canplay` and `canplaythrough` but nothing happend!

#### NOTICE:

I have tested this code and **success** on:

- IE11 / Windows Phone 8.1
- Android Browser / Android 4.1,4.3

And **Fail** on:

- Safari / iPhone 4, 4S
- Firefox, Chrome / Android 4.1,4.3

Comment: So, this is nothing to do with 'canplay'? It seems to me like the issue here is more to do with there being a disconnect between the user interaction and the call to 'play()' - ie click -> ajax ==/== canplay -> play().
Any chance this question's title could be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile devices require direct, physical, **synchronous** interaction from the user to play audio or video. You've avoided the common pitfall of trying to play audio on page load by requiring the user to actually click a button, but you've broken the synchronous rule by making an asynchronous request with `$.getJSON`. You have stumbled across one of the **only** exceptions to the "**never use synchronous XHRs**" rule. I have never recommended this before, but try replacing your `play()` function with this:

```
function play() {
    var audioId = $("#btnPlayPause").attr('playing'); //get id of audio

    $.ajax({
        url:"/wap.php/AjaxLoadAudio"
        data: { audio_id: audioId },
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            realSounder.src = response.audio_share_url;
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got that!

Comment: Is there a way to make the audio element queue the audio, so that there is no delay before it actually plays? On Android, I set the audio element's src attribute, and then wait for the 'canplay' event before I enable the play button. With iOS, it seems like it won't emit the 'canplay' until after calling play() on it. That doesn't make much sense to me, tbh, so I'm wondering if I have something wrong.